# The return value of data using ajax, jquery, json

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

please, can you help me with this? I am a beginner in programming, so if it's a stupid question, have a patience with me. Thank you.

I have index.php page with login form (username, password) and login.php with this part of a code:

```
<? if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password']){
$data['msg'] = 'All fields have to be filled!';
$data['success'] = false;}else{


mysql_query("   INSERT INTO log_access(user,ip,datetime)
                            VALUES(
                            '".$_POST['username']."',
                            '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',
                            NOW()
                            )");

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,login FROM users WHERE login='".$username."' AND pwd='".md5($password)."'"));

if($row['login'])
{
    $_SESSION['login'] = $row['login'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];

    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['redirect'] = "index.php";    
}
else 
{
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['msg']='Wrong username or password!';
}}echo json_encode($data);?>
```

If i send empty field(s) in username or/and password, login.php return $data. But if i send filled fields, no data is comming back to index.php. 
I have the following in index.php:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() 
            { 
                $('#frmLogin').submit(function() 
                { 
                    $.post('/scripts/login.php',{username: $('[name=username]').val(), password: $('[name=password]').val()}, function(data)
                        {
                            if(data.success)
                            {
                                $('#login-msg').html("Logged");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $('#login-msg').html(data.msg);
                            }
                        }
                        ,'json');
            return false; 
        }); 
            }); 
</script>
```

I have the same problem if I put anything in the first condition, or before it (in login.php). 
I don't know, what i'm doing wrong :(

Thank for any help!
Washa

**EDIT**
SOLVED! 
I have bad connection to the DB from the login script. Beginners mistake. Thanks for all replies.

Comment: Can you check Firebug's console and see if the POST is happening and the response code is 200. you can also check what response is being retrieved.

Comment: Thanks for help. I checked it. The POST is happening, status 200 OK. But in response i have error msg: Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) in /DISK2/WWW/washa.cz/nexnetkm/scripts/ajax_login2.php on line 5

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /DISK2/WWW/washa.cz/nexnetkm/scripts/ajax_login2.php on line 5
{"msg":"V\u0161echna pol\u00ed\u010dka mus\u00ed b\u00fdt vypln\u011bna!","success":false}

Comment: ok now you need to fix ur mysql connection and try again.

Comment: I'm not a PHP developer, but it looks like you need some data sanitization.

Comment: SOLVED! Thank you very much. The FireBug helps a lot. Great plugin. The problem was really with the connection. So i added: include(db_connection.php) - which i'm using in index.php for example. It works. Thank you very much again. My mistake, small problem at all, but huge for me :D

Comment: That's nice. Please accept the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check Firebug's console and see if the POST is happening and the response code is 200? you can also check what response is being retrieved.

try calling a test.php with the following contents:

```
<?
 if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password']){
$data['msg'] = 'All fields have to be filled!';
$data['success'] = false;
}else{
$data['success'] = true;
$data['redirect'] = "index.php";  
echo json_encode($_POST);
}
?>
```

Also check if the username and password are being passed in correctly by doing

```
alert( $('[name=username]').val() + | + $('[name=password]).val());
```

just above $.post.

I checked your js by hardcoding username and password, they are working fine.
its usually a good idea to divide and conquer. hardcode the input for your login.php page, and run it first, after its working then make your $_POST params as the input. this way you could prevent a lot of problems.

```
 ****Important Please ESCAPE ALL POST OR GET VARIABLES FOR MYSQL INSERT.
   Otherwise your scripts are vulnerable to SQL injections.
    ex: mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
Please ignore if you are already doing this!
```

Comment: thanks for reply, if i try only this simple code, it works. But when i add for example connection to the DB and some function like $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); i have an error...